# User Information form lost after sp-moveuser

Tags: user-profile

in my test lab, after executing the cmdlet **SP-MoveUser** the form that displays the user information (the one that appears when you click on the user display name) is lost and cannot be viewed anymore.

This issue happens only for the users for which I execute **SP-MoveUser**.

Did you ever noticed this before? Is there any fix to this?

Thanks

Comment: Move-SPUser?  What patch level is your farm at?  There is a bug prior to the June 2011 CU for SharePoint 2010 where SharePoint was incapable of migrating users.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, even because my farm has not patch level at all :). I should try to apply SP1 at least. I'll be back after SP1 installation. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now that we know you're not at any patch level, the resolution to your issue should be apply SP1 + at least [June 2011 CU](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536599) as the June CU solves the migration issue, however, I would recommend [Feb 2012 CU](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597150) instead.